# known issues with jqxGrid('setcellvalue')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

Are there any known issues for doing a 'setcellvalue'?

```
var bGrid = $('#jqxBOMGrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
for (var i = 0; i < bGrid.length; ++i) {
    if( <<bGrid[i] == the one I want to find >> ) {        
        console.log("tko", Tko, "qty", qty, typeof (qty), "idx", i, bGrid[i]);
        $('#jqxBOMGrid').jqxGrid('setcellvalue', i, "Qty", qty);
    }
}
```

I’ve proven ‘i’ is the valid value of the index 4 in this case.
And ‘Qty’ is the string “8”.

Here is the error

[image]

This is the grid:

```
$('#jqxBOMGrid').jqxGrid({
    width: 1400
    , height: 700
    , source: daBOMGrid
    , enableellipsis: true
    , editable: true
    , filterable: true
    , autoshowfiltericon: true
    , sortable: true
    , columns: [
        { text: 'Qty', datafield: 'Qty', width: 50, cellsalign: 'center', columntype: 'textbox', sortable: false, editable: false },
        { text: 'QtyPreEdit', datafield: 'QtyPreEdit', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Id', datafield: 'PartID', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'CategoryPartsID', datafield: 'CategoryPartsID', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Tko P/n', datafield: 'TkoPartNo', width: 60, cellsalign: 'left', editable: false, sortable: true },
        { text: 'Mfg P/n', datafield: 'ManuPartNo', width: 200, cellsalign: 'left', editable: false, sortable: true },
        { text: 'Manufacturer', datafield: 'Manufacturer', width: 200, cellsalign: 'left', editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Description', datafield: 'PartDescript', width: 600, cellsalign: 'left', editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Status', datafield: 'Status', width: 100, cellsalign: 'right', editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'UnitOfMeasure', datafield: 'UnitOfMeasure', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Voltage', datafield: 'Voltage', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Website', datafield: 'Website', width: 100, cellsalign: 'right', editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'Spare %', datafield: 'SparePercentage', width: 70, cellsalign: 'right', editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'DateCreated', datafield: 'DateCreated', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'DateModified', datafield: 'DateModified', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false },
        { text: 'ModifiedLastBy', datafield: 'ModifiedLastBy', hidden: true, editable: false, sortable: false }
    ]
});
```

What might I be able to do to troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has become evident to me that this line of code generates this error:

```
$('#jqxBOMGrid').jqxGrid('setcellvalue', i, "QtyPreEdit", j.Qty);
```

But this time does not.

```
$('#jqxBOMGrid').jqxGrid('setcellvalue', i, 'QtyPreEdit', j.Qty);
```

The difference being the use of double-quotes -v- single-quotes.